# Why don't any of Create-React-App's outputted build files contain a __webpack_require__ function

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I'm not yet very familiar with Webpack, but to my understanding, all builds should include a `__webpack_require__` function. However, inspecting my Create React App build output, none of the files have it at all. Why is this? Is that function not actually necessary in some cases?